# Как сделать что бы при добавлении товаров в заказ после добавленного купона скидки к последующим товарам применялись тоже

Tags: wordpress

Когда я создаю заказ в админке woocommerce и добавляю какие-то товары, а затем применяю купон, то скидка работает только на товары уже в корзине и не работает на следующие добавленные товары. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Нажать "пересчитать". Я только что проверил - работает. https://transfer.sh/pctJAJGbcb/2023-11-10_22-39-37.mp4 Если у тебя не работает - давай больше подробностей.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но в видео по ссылке после того, как ты добавил новые товарыы после купона и нажал пересчитать, то скидка на новые товары не добаваилась - там была скидка по купона 100р и так осталась, вот в чем вопрос

Comment: А что ещё должно было добавиться, если купон на 100 руб? Ты рассказывай свои правила купонов.

Comment: да, в примере купон на 100р, но я имею ввиду, что до добавления последних двух товаров, скидка равномерно делится на первые три товара (отображается скидка 33,3р) и на последние 2 товара после рекалькуляции она не отображается для последних товаров, все так же отображается олько для первых трех, как и было.
В моем случае я использую процентную скидку, при добавлении всех товаров после скидки она не рассчитывается:
https://transfer.sh/O9AaNjkhSA/12-57-05.mov

Comment: я нашел хук, который с этим работает и позволяет пересчитать скидку для всех товаров, но он запускается и работает только если я добавляю или удаляю Fee, а это не о функционал, 
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_totals_after_discount', 'recalculate_fee_for_all_products');
function recalculate_fee_for_all_products($order_id) {
   $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
   $order->recalculate_coupons();
}

больше мне никак не уудалось пересчитаь скидку на все продукты - woocommerce_before_calculate_totals и woocommerce_calculate_totals тоже не срабатываеют при этом

Comment: Да, действительно косяк - при %м купоне скидка не пересчитывается. Но есть костыльный выход - удалить и снова добавить купон. Кроме того я обнаружил и другие косяков с купонами при удалении товаров.. Можешь написать багрепорты в автоматик.

Comment: А можешь подсказать, как при добавлении товара в корзину удалять и добавлять купон? у меня в админке это не срабатывает с хуками, которые я указал выше и не работает с хуком woocommerce_new_order_item

Comment: В админке вручную удалить и потом добавить купон https://i.imgur.com/MRpHlFo.jpeg

Comment: А, ну удалить и добавить это да, я просто хотел хоть как-то автоматизировать это при добавлении товара в админке через хук. Но ладно, спасибо за ответ)